# Transferring a tab separated variable file via clipboard to Excel but retaining line breaks WITHIN the cell

Tags: c#, excel, csv, clipboard

I am using C# Script in Tabular Editor to read a Power BI file and use clipboard to get information to Excel. Totally newbie to both so my code isn't great but works. My code is below.

For the Expression field I am using .Replace("\n"," ") to replace the line breaks with a blank space.

Otherwise the line broken text moves into the next row in Excel and doesn't align with the corresponding column anymore.

Is there a way I can achieve both
i.e. replace the line breaks with something in Excel that is recognized as a multiple line but still remains with in an Excel Cell.
I have googled and read multiple threads and tried \r, \x0A, CHAR(10), WrapText in Excel etc.

```
var tsv = "Table_Name\tTable_MeasureCount\tMeasure_Name\tMeasure_Description\tMeasure_DisplayFolder\tMeasure_IsHidden\tMeasure_DataType\tMeasure_FormatString\tMeasure_DataCategory\tMeasure_ErrorMessage\tMeasure_Expression";

foreach(var Table in Model.Tables)

    foreach(var Measure in Table.Measures)
        {
            tsv += "\r\n" + Table.Name
            + "\t" + Table.Measures.Count 
            + "\t" + Measure.Name 
            + "\t" + Measure.Description
            + "\t" + Measure.DisplayFolder
            + "\t" + Measure.IsHidden
            + "\t" + Measure.DataType 
            + "\t" + Measure.FormatString
            + "\t" + Measure.DataCategory
            + "\t" + Measure.ErrorMessage.Replace("\n"," ")
            + "\t" + Measure.Expression.Replace("\n"," ");
        }

tsv.Output();
```

Comment: Does it have to be tab delimited? According to rfc-4180, if you comma delimit you can simply wrap each string in quotes `"` and leave the CRLF's in place.

Comment: It doesn't have to be tab delimited. Only did that due to my limited knowledge. I can try changing to comma delimited but assume will have to do an extra step after transferring to Excel. There are " and commas already in the Expression text so don't know whether that will confuse it.

Comment: You only need the "quotes" around strings. but the strings you place quotes around you and to replace any single `"` with `""` to escape them. any commas without the string will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we have established CSV is the best option as it allows for line-breaks, I'd suggest the following:

First create a simple function to parse a string into a safe format:

```
  public string stringToCsvSafe(string str)
  {
    return "\"" + str.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
  }
```

Then in your loop build your output string, something like this:

```
var newRow = new List<object>() { 
    Table.Name, 
    Table.Measures.Count, 
    stringToCsvSafe(Measure.Name), 
    stringToCsvSafe(Measure.Description),
    ...
};
csv += string.Join(",", newRow) + "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you I got it working. For some reason I couldn't get the function to work when in Tabular Editor so I just repeated the code

Answer (score 1):

This is the logic I ended up with (I couldn't get a function to work in Tabular Editor)

```
var csv = "\"Table_Name\",\"Table_MeasureCount\",\"Measure_Name\",\"Measure_Description\",\"Measure_DisplayFolder\",\"Measure_IsHidden\",\"Measure_DataType\",\"Measure_FormatString\",\"Measure_DataCategory\",\"Measure_ErrorMessage\",\"Measure_Expression\"";

string str1 = "\r\n\"";
string str2 = "\",\"";
string str3 = "\"";

//foreach(var Measure in Model.AllMeasures)
foreach(var Table in Model.Tables)
    {
    foreach(var Measure in Table.Measures)
        {
            csv += str1 + Table.Name
            + str2 + Table.Measures.Count
            + str2 + Measure.Name
            + str2 + Measure.Description
            + str2 + Measure.DisplayFolder
            + str2 + Measure.IsHidden
            + str2 + Measure.DataType
            + str2 + Measure.FormatString.Replace("\"","\"\"")
            + str2 + Measure.DataCategory
            + str2 + Measure.ErrorMessage.Replace("\"","\"\"")
            + str2 + Measure.Expression.Replace("\"","\"\"") 
            + str3;
        }
    }
            
csv.Output();
```